# UICollectionViewCell not calling updateConstraints automatically when dequeued?

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a UICollectionViewCell subclass. I wrote an `updateConstraints` method as I've done a hundred times before. For some reason that is never called when the cell is dequeued. I had to add a manual call to `[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` after dequeueing it.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Implement this method and return YES. This could probably help.

```
+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout
```

For details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616469/1300262