# Autolayout Width Constants in UICollectionViewCell doesn't work well

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2, uicollectionviewcell

Below is a uicollectionviewcell, bar width must be according to number at right of it (vote count), event I log its width contants in console you can see it's calculated correctly, but on ui, two of them seems doesn't work well, if I scroll collectionview for several times it will be fixed, and then it will be fail again, how to set a view's contraint contant in a cell correctly?

[image]

code is too long but I want to summarize here
1) in viewcontroller's cellForItem
cell.setup()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell

2) in cell's setup()
setupBarWidths()

3) in setupBardWidhts()
resetAllWitdhs -> 0
calculate and set widths

is this correct way?

Comment: Show your code please?

Comment: Looks like a cell reuse issue. try to implement prepareForReuse in your cell, and set the constraint to 0.

Comment: added my code summary check please

Comment: @turushan, Did you create autolayout constraint for width? or did you just change the frame and call layoutIfNeeded ?

Comment: @Doro working with storyboard created width contraint, end setting it in code according to calculations

Comment: @turushan, please, review updated answer

Comment: I have exactly the same issue: "if I scroll collectionview for several times it will be fixed" - did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you are setting your constants for your subview inside uicollectionviewcell.

If your cell does not update properly constraints, possible solution is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616848/2382237)

You must provide separate width constraint for your horizontal bar, and set it every time your reload cell.

> "if I scroll collectionview for several times it will be fixed"

This problem occurs when you does not handle properly constraints changing, for example,you have "if - else " clause in your code, and you don't implement one branch.

Anyway, it's much easier to provide solution if you share your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`

UPDATED:

UICollectionView has many bugs internal, so one possible solution is to override UICollectionViewCell and insert the following method:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      contentView.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804588/auto-layout-in-uicollectionviewcell-not-working) thread for more info.

Comment: added my code summary check please, I'm handling if else cases, mostly, cell is not good at first initialize, then it fixes itself after out screen, in screen...